# How can I get javascript parsing to work in Visual Studio 2013

Tags: javascript, visual-studio-2013

In Visual Studio 2013 Update 4 with the code shown in the below screenshot the brace matching is off. See the red arrows. Is there a way to make this work? I found it impossible to edit javascript in VS with this problem because this matching feeds the auto indent and the file would indent in all sorts of wrong ways.

[image: image of IDE messing up brace matching]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think it's due to the use of [`for( ..of ..)`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Statements/for...of), which is an experimental feature, in a draft state, not supported by Internet Explorer, and therefore apparently not supported by VS either (note the wiggly line under `to`).

If VS sees the for loop as a syntax error, that will probably also cause the parentheses mismatch.

Comment: I think you are right because "var x in container" works. However, I would say Microsoft made some horrible decisions in their brace matching "technology" because the brace match should be the same regardless of what's inside the parentheses. A toddler could match the branches correctly in this case!

Comment: Yes, but toddlers are humans, and they have very different pattern matching capabilities than computers. You could also argue that the parser finds an invalid word or sequence of words inside the expression, so it can argue that someone forgot the closing parentheses of the for loop. Playing Devil's advocate, though, because I agree that ideally it would do the match as you describe. But if they change it, I can promise that someone else will complain. :)

Comment: True toddlers are complicated. But I think a requirement here should have been that parse errors should not break brace matching. Suppose this were a typo not an experimental syntax, I would not want indentation of my whole file thrown off because I have a very localized parse error inside some inner parens. I think they made a very poor choice somewhere along the line. Their way probably does some neat things, but it fails on the basics.